# http 406 error on restful web service

Tags: apache-flex, spring, http, rest, spring-mvc

I have Spring MVC + JAXB web service and Flex client. I am getting HTTP 406 error when using RestFUL API. Here is request and response headers on image:

[image]

Can you help me for solving this problem?

Comment: does it work if you go to the url from the browser directly?

Comment: yes i can get the results if i directly use the rest service from url.

Comment: so compare the two requests and see what's different and post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem comes when the data returned from the server is not in the format that is excepted by the browser. Also this can be caused by any one of the following:

- **Accept**: The MIME types accepted by the browser. For example, HTML files, GIF files etc.
- **Accept-Charset**: The character sets accepted by the client, e.g. utf-8, iso-8859-1 etc.
- **Accept-Encoding**: The data encoding accepted by the client e.g. the file formats it understands, e.g. gzip.
- **Accept-Language**: The natural languages (English, German etc.) accepted by the client.

Check what the server is returning and fix the problem!

Comment: I put the headers. Could you see any weird, unmatched headers?

Comment: sdch is implemented in Chrome. I don't know about it in other browsers. If the response is encoded in that format then your browser may not be able to decode it or deflate has some compatibility issue. You can check that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574168/deflate-compression-browser-compatibility-and-advantages-over-gzip)

Comment: great. My projects works on IE and Firefox. Then the problem is Chrome I think. Here is another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105670/how-to-get-around-content-encoding-gzip-deflate-header-sent-by-chrome